# How to create a list of multiple vectors with **names** and **paste** in R

Tags: r

I beginner in R and I need a little help with this problem:

Creates a list called unif that contains 1000 vectors of 20 elements each of a uniform distribution (runif). Name the vectors from vect1, vect2......to vect1000. Review functions names and paste.

I just have done this:

```
 unif <- NULL
 for(i in 1:1000){unif[i]<- list(runif(i))}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's usually good form to mark homework help as such.

Comment: Where to begin ... In your code what will `runif(i)`  do?

Comment: `replicate` is a better idea than `for` here.

Comment: Agreed but OP says he needs a list

Comment: Agree with @alistaire.  Or even `split(runif(20 * 1000), paste0("vect", 1:1000))` because we have vectorization and recycling.

Comment: @EvanFriedland `simplify = FALSE`

Comment: Thanks guys, a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:
To add to a list, you want to initialize the empty list first

```
 unif <- list()
```

Then, to incrementally edit/add/remove list elements we use the subsetting method of double brackets `[[`.

You say you want 20 unif elements per vector. The first argument of runif is the size - so you want 20 there- not 'i'

Then after creating each new list element, we use names to change create a new name with paste0.

```
for(i in 1:1000){unif[[i]] <- runif(20)} 
names(unif) <- paste0("vect", 1:1000)
unif
```

Comment: Allocating the list length prior to running the loop will improve efficiency quite a bit.

Comment: Edited so that names actually works correctly. As Rich says, you can initialize the list length using something like unif <- rep(list(rep(NA,20)), 1000)    but I don't know if there is really a speed improvement at this level of process